# How to prevent Asp.Net Core from referencing dependencies from Runtime Store

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing a web application using Asp.NET Core **2.1** on Visual Studio **17.7**, the problem is when I publish the web app as a Framework-Dependent and I try to run the app on production machine I get this error message:

```
Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Example.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Cronos', version: '0.6.3'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.0/Cronos.dll'
```

Cronos.dll is a dependency of Hangfire library which I am using in the web app, in the Example.deps.json file I found this:

```
"Cronos/0.6.3": {
    "dependencies": {
      "NETStandard.Library": "2.0.3"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "lib/netstandard1.0/Cronos.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "0.6.3.0",
        "fileVersion": "0.6.3.0"
      }
    },
    "compile": {
      "lib/netstandard1.0/Cronos.dll": {}
    }
  },
```

The problem is that it's referencing the libraries in the runtime store, which will work on the developemnt machine but when I deploy to another machine the error happens.

I have tried the suggested solution in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store

By setting:-

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and I have also tried solutions in this github issue with no success:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13542

Comment: How are you deploying this application?

Comment: I copy the release folder content to the server and execute this command dotnet Example.dll

Comment: Did you try dotnet publish?

Comment: Is that how you created the release folder?

Comment: Yes with the publish option in Visual Studio

Comment: Did you use the `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish` folder? the publish output is in this subfolder of the build output

Comment: You are right, the issue is that I was running the web application from the root file, I just tried running the other dll file inside the publish folder and the application started successfully

Comment: the question is why there is two dll files?, one is in the release root folder and the other is inside the publish folder.

Comment: Could you add your comment as an answer? @MartinUllrich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deploying a .NET Core application, only use the publish output from the `bin/Release/netcoreapp*/publish` or `…/netcoreapp*/{RID}/publish` (when using `-r RID` option) or call `dotnet publish` with an `-o ../target-dir` option to specify a publish target location.

The build output (`bin/Release/netcoreapp*`) is meant for development purposes only since the `runtimeconfig.dev.json` file configures .NET Core to use packages directly from your NuGet package cache which avoids copying assets during the development builds.